# Get all related articles from given article using eager loading

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I want to get all related articles of particular article based on category.

I have relation between `Article` and `Category`

**Article.php**

```
public function category(){

    return $this->belongsTo(ArticleCategory::class,'category_id','id');

}
```

**ArticleCategory.php**

```
 public function articles(){

    return $this->hasMany(Article::class,'category_id','id');

}
```

**ArticleController.php**

```
public function singleArticle(Article $article){

    //I want to convert this statement to eager loading statement

    $relatedArticles = $article->category->articles;

    return view('pages/article',compact('article','relatedArticles'));

}
```

Comment: You could try `$article->load('category.articles')->get();`

Comment: or you could do `$relatedArticles = Article::with('category')->where('id','!=', $article->id)->where('category_id', $article->category_id)->get();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `whereHas()` if you want to just get related articles:

```
$relatedArticles = Article::whereHas('category', function($q) use($article) {
    $q->where('id', $article->category_id);
})
->get();
```

If you want load everything to one collection:

```
$relatedArticles = Article::with(['category.articles' => function($q) use($article) {
    $q->where('id', $article->category_id);
}])
->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna have the category model always eager load its articles out of the box, you could add

```
protected $with = ['articles'];
```

to the Category.php file.

With that you then could just use $article->category

This also works for the implicit bindings in a function call, so you could eager load category for every article when you write in Article.php

```
protected $with = ['category'];
```

Sadly if you wanna eagerload everything with

```
protected $with = ['category.articles'];
```

you get an endless loop in this case. Just for info for similar cases in the future, you can do nested eager loading with this.